# A successfully failed SQL Server Agent job? - The statement has been terminated. Message 3621. The step succeeded

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-job

I have a SQL Server Job which has some steps include execution of store procedures. The job ran successfully. However, some steps which executes store procedure did not run fully as per my understanding. The message is

> The statement has been terminated. Message 3621. The step succeeded.

[image]

The highlighted steps should run longer than in the screen shot. Because these stored procedures include insertion of millions of rows into destination table. It works perfectly fine when I run these stored procedures from SSMS. I don't understand why this is happening from SQL Server Job Agent?

I have configured the job if any step fails it will quit the job.
[image]

[image]

Comment: For each step you can choose what to do on success and what to do on failure and the choices are the same for both. So you can for example on the Advanced page choose to "Quit the job reporting success." as the On Failure action and "Quit the job reporting failure.' as the On Success option if you really want to confuse people.

Comment: @Brian, Job has been configured like that only.

Comment: Show the Advanced page of the job step properties of one of the steps in question.

Comment: You will also have to show the script for the text. Its quite easy to have a statement fail, but the step pass, such as if the fail has been caught inside the sctript.